# What is the best way to prepare walls, windows and baseboard for re-painting

Tags: painting, spackling-paste, paint-removal

I would like to repaint our appartment that haven't been paintined for over 7 years.  I have a question on how to prepare for the new paint.
The walls have chipped paint a little should i use spackle to even it out?

The biggest thing is the window.  The paint is really coming off there.  I scrapped the paint where i could.  I don't really want to scrape everything off.  What should i do next?  Do I need use spackle to fill the parts where i took of the paint?  Can i use DAP fast 'n final light weight spackle?
[image]

[image]

Also i have the same problem with the baseboard.  The paint is chipping and it is not even. Should i also chip off the paint and use spackle before priming?
[image]

Thank you!

Update!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are more pictures of the wall and windows where i took off some paint.  Also the paint on the radiator is pilling off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting is easy - preparing for a new coat of paint so it will last is the hard work.

You should scrape off all loose or peeling paint - otherwise the new paint will simply peel right off there. Only after that should you move to spackle and sanding to prepare the base for new paint. On wood items "putty" is preferred over "spackle" which is more of a drywall/plaster repair item, though it's somewhat irrelevant when it's being painted over.

The window looks like you should investigate for and fix a leak. If it gets that wet, new paint won't stick either.

The dark spot in the second picture is in the same place on all the pictures so it's a camera defect, I guess - at first it looked like mold.

The blisters in the third - more leakage? Or pitch bubbling out of the wood?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!  The dark spot is a defect on my phone not on the wall :)  The window doesn't leak it was just old caulk that i had to scrape off.  I will caulk it again before painting.  I updated the question with some more pictures where i took some of the paint.  In the window i would use putty to cover the places where i took off the paint  to even it out with the old paint?  Would you recommend the putty i would need to use?  On the walls also i have to use spackle everywhere to even out with the existing paint?

Comment: Another quick question.  Can i use the  DAP fast 'n final light weight spackle to cover the areas where i took off the paint or i would have to use putty or mix some other compound?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the wood trim around the window I would remove all the existing paint with a heat gun and scraper.

The alternative would be to use coarse, then fine, sandpaper to smooth out the paint as well as possible then paint over it and live with the remaining surface imperfections. Trying to putty or spackle that smooth will be difficult at best and will require just as much work to make it look good.

Same with the baseboards, or consider removing and replacing the baseboard moldings. It might actually be easier and faster than trying to smooth them out.

Lightweight spackle works good, I would use that on the walls. It does take a while to dry enough to sand, but careful application for small cracks and chips may not need to be sanded if you are using flat (no gloss) paint. For glossy paint it **must** be fine sanded and primed or you will see a difference is the surface finish.